# Show String Collection Editor by clicking another button

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, sharpdevelop

I have a custom property in a property grid. Is it possible to show the String Collection Editor by clicking an ordinary button instead by doing the usual way, clicking the elipses?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an Visual Studio usability issue. Following steps should save your time-

Prerequisites/Assumptions -

1. Pin Properties Window and Select "Attribute" property by clicking the "Attribute" text
2. Scroll "Properties Window" so that you can see the "Attribute" propery clearly
3. There are multiple controls on same forms. Only single property will be mofieid at a time.

Now follow the steps -

1. Select Control to modify from Desiger
2. Hit **F4 + F4 (twice)**
3. String Collection Editor will appear
4. Make changes and click OK
5. Select other control to modify and follow all above steps for all controls

Above thing will save your time.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What I mean is I want to activate (show) that String Collection Editor by clicking some button instead of the elipses in the property grid...

Comment: And where do you want to put that new button? If you want to replace that elipses with some other button then I dont think that it is possible. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? Why do you want to place a button?

Comment: I'm not replacing the elipses. What I'm trying to achieve is to make an alternative shortcut, a keydown maybe, not necessarily a button click to make the editor show instead of clicking the elipses.

Comment: I'm not getting the exact motive behind such requirement. All I can figure out is there are lot of such controls in your project and you want some kind of shortcut to update Attribute property in less time. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes. Actually, this property grid has plenty of custom properties. So what I'm trying to achive is assign a shortcut (a keydwon) for each property. E.g. if I hit F1, the String Collection Editor for property1 will show. F2 to show the String Editor for property2, and so on... By this, I thnk it will be more handy than scrolling the mouse on that tiny elipses button for each property..

Comment: I have modified the answer above. It is all I can figure out and steps works for me in VS2008. Let me know it helps you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15566/discussion-between-paragm-and-yonan2236)

Comment: sorry I was not able to get back into you. I'm not actually a .Net Developer or inline with Microsoft technologies and it is not allowed in our office to use Visual Studio. I'm using the open source IDE, SharpDevelop. I'm not able to get your instructions.